# Django display specific text if date is older than 10 days

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I'm working on a project for a customer who wants to display 'Alert' in a table if a users join date is older than ten days.  I don't want to use a filter to only return the objects that satisfy the query because I want to display all of the members in the table.  I'm using Django 2.x and python 3.6.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

models.py:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50,)
    join_date = models.DateField('Join Date', auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False,)
```

views.py:

```
def memberList(request, template_name='members/memberList.html'):
    member = Member.objects.all()
    data = {}
    data['object_list'] = member
    return render(request, template_name, data)
```

and my template, memberList.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Join Date</th>
            <th>Alert</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for member in object_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ member.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ member.join_date }}</td>
            <td> **??**</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hey, did my or [olinox14's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279120/olinox14) answer work for you? If yes, please accept either of these as a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add a method to your model, like that:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50,)
    join_date = models.DateField('Join Date', auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False,)

    def older_than_ten_days(self):
        return (datetime.date.today() - self.join_date).days > 10
```

Then your template simply become:

```
    <tr>
        <td>{{ member.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ member.join_date }}</td>
        <td>{{ member.older_than_ten_days }}</td>
    </tr>
```

However, if you need to pass more parameters to the method, like a variable number of days, you have to use the [Aleksander Zień solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54331220/4279120)

Comment: nice, works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two ways you can achieve that

## Method-lookup approach

**edit:** Credits for this one goes to [olinox14](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279120/olinox14), I didn't see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54331679/5337455) while editting mine.

First, make sure you understand what is written in [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls) about **Accessing method calls** from within templates.

What you will find the most interesting for your cause there is:

> (...) And of course you can easily access methods you’ve explicitly defined on your own models

Keeping that in mind, I encourage you to check [olinox14's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54331679/5337455).

## Custom template tag approach

You can use Django templates' if statement and use custom template tag to calculate actual result. It should look something like

```py
from django import template
import datetime 


register = template.Library() 


@register.filter(expects_localtime=True)
def is_older_than_ten_days(value):
    if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
        value = value.date()
    delta = value - datetime.date.today()
    return delta.days > 10
```

And then in your template use it like this:

```
(...)
        {% for member in object_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ member.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ member.join_date }}</td>
            <td>{% if member.join_date|is_older_than_ten_days %}YOUR INFO
                {% else %}something else{% endif %}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
(...)
```

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31564166/5337455) for more details.

Comment: I'm trying to use this on the User model, but I get **TemplateSyntaxError**

Answer (score 0):

You can get all objects and then add a field to each object whether that is 10 days old or not.You can assign a boolean variable lets say isOld and render in template by `{% if isOld %}` like this:

```
import datetime
def memberList(request, template_name='members/memberList.html'):
    data={}
    members = Member.objects.all()
    for i in members:

        delta=datetime.datetime.today() - i.join_date
        if delta.days < 10:
           i.isOld=False
        else:
           i.isOld=True
    data["object_list"]=members
    return render(request, template_name, data)
```

In your template you can:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Join Date</th>
        <th>Alert</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for member in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ member.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ member.join_date }}</td>
        {% if member.isOld %}
        <td style="color:red;"> Old Alert</td>
        {% else %}
        <td style="color:green;"> New Alert</td>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Models.object.filter for filtering out in views.py

Like see what I have done in my project is used HTML default date for date picking i.e. proj1/templates/tasks.html

```
<form method="POST" action="/tasks/">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="date" value="date" id="date" name="date">
      <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

then in proj1/app1/models.py

```
class Tasks01(models.Model):
registerdb4 = models.ForeignKey(Register, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Ename = models.CharField(u'Name of employee', max_length=100)
supervisor_name = models.CharField(u'Supervisor Name', max_length=100, blank=True)
title = models.CharField(u'Title', max_length=200)
description = models.TextField(u'Description')
day = models.DateField(u'Date')
start_time = models.TimeField(u'Starting Time')
end_time = models.TimeField(u'Ending Time')

def __str__(self):
    return "%s %s" %(self.Ename, self.day)
```

then in proj1/app1/views.py

```
def tasks(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    date01 = request.POST['date']
    s1 = request.session['session_id']
    if Tasks01.objects.filter(day=date01).exists():
        print('yes')
        task = Tasks01.objects.filter(day=date01,registerdb4=s1)
        return render(request, "tasks.html", {'task': task})
    else:
        print("no records")
        return render(request, "tasks.html")
return render(request, "tasks.html")
```